# How to add SCNNode as a child to parent without changing relative position, size and scale in world coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

I have two SCNNodes, `nodeCh` and `nodePrnt`. Their world coordinates are available and their relative position/size/angle should remain the same.

I want to add `nodeCh` to the `nodePrnt` as a child, by using `- (void)addChildNode:(SCNNode)` method. In order to do that I should translate the world coordinates/size/angles of `nodeCh` in terms of relative position/scale/rotation of `nodePrnt` so that the relative positions/scale/sizes won't change comparing to the case when both nodes are added to `scene.rootNode` as children.

Clearly, I have to use some combination of transform operators. Currently I am using the following lines which work incorrectly:

```
SCNMatrix4 transform
    = [self.nodePrnt convertTransform:SCNMatrix4Identity
                              fromNode:nil];

nodeChld.transform = transform;
```

Comment: It's incredible Apple haven't realized that 3D engines need "change parent (without moving)" as a basic!

Answer (score 3):

Conversion utils are indeed what you'll need to use.
In your case:

```
nodeCh.transform = [nodePrnt convertTransform:SCNMatrix4Identity fromNode:nodeCh];
```

or

```
nodeCh.transform = [nodeCh convertTransform:SCNMatrix4Identity toNode:nodePrnt];
```

Comment: thx, that helped, seems like I failed to put two and two together

Comment: Thanks this is exactly I was looking for - how to convert back them to child ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick helper method inspired by SpriteKit.

**Swift 5.2**

```
extension SCNNode {
    func move(toParent parent: SCNNode) {
        let convertedTransform = convertTransform(SCNMatrix4Identity, to: parent)
        removeFromParentNode()
        transform = convertedTransform
        parent.addChildNode(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly I was looking for - how to convert back them to child ? –